# Can a Tk canvas import a postscript file and display it?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas, postscript

I'm trying to draw vector graphics on a canvas using Python's Tkinter and I was excited when I noticed that canvases have a postscript() method that can save the contents of the canvas to a Postscript file and it's fairly trivial to losslessly convert SVG to EPS.

My question is this: can it do the reverse?  Can I take a postscript file from the disk and unpack it onto the canvas?  Is Tk a powerful enough graphics toolkit for that?

or would I be better off just rendering the svg down to a GIF image (or parsing the EPS file using PIL and converting it to a pixel array that way) and displaying that?

Comment: The reverse direction is orders of magnitude more difficult; no such capability is built in.  The PIL/Pillow module can convert EPS to a Tkinter-compatible image, but it requires an external program called ghostscript to do so.  Rendering SVG to a Canvas would be much simpler, but I'm not aware of any module for doing so.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> Can a Tk canvas import a postscript file and display it?

No, it cannot.